# Undefined method 'page' for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my controller

```
def show
    @intents= @user.intents.page(1).per(2)
end
```

and in my view

```
= paginate @intents
```

and end up with `undefined method 'page' for #<...::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy>`

Comment: Do you have `kaminari` in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes. I did it in console and it works

Comment: Have you restarted the server after installing the gem?

Comment: u are right. i didn't.